# Filter videos to be displayed on the basis of a property in json in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have 4 buttons in my html code. On click of each button, I want the videos to get filtered on the basis of "type" value in the json.
Here is the code:

```
    <div class="btn-group hidden-xs" id = "selectBtns">
  <button ng-repeat = "button in buttons" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-model = "selectedButton" ng-class="{focused: isFocused($index+1)}" ng-click="selectButton($index+1)">{{button.value}}</button>
</div>
```

The div which displays the image:

```
<div ng-repeat = "videos in src | filter :{type: selectedButton}" class="col-sm-4 onlineVideos">
<video controls>
<source src={{videos.src}} type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The json:

```
"source": 
[
    {
    "src" : "videos/study.mp4",
    "type" : "Development"
    },
    {
    "src" : "videos/study.mp4",
    "type" : "Development"
    },
    {
    "src" : "videos/study.mp4",
    "type" : "Development"
    },
    {
    "src" : "videos/study.mp4",
    "type" : "Designing"
    },
    {
    "src" : "videos/study.mp4",
    "type" : "Designing"
    },
    {
    "src" : "videos/study.mp4",
    "type" : "Designing"
    },
    {
    "src" : "videos/study.mp4",
    "type" : "Tools"
    },
    {
    "src" : "videos/study.mp4",
    "type" : "Tools"
    },
    {
    "src" : "videos/study.mp4",
    "type" : "Tools"
    }
]
```

Comment: use $ctrl.selectedButton instead of selectedButton as this might be a problem related to scope of a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button>` element does not support `ng-model` (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). You can either use a `select` element or use `ng-click` to update the model.

**View**

```
<button ng-repeat="button in buttons" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{focused: isFocused($index+1)}" ng-click="selectButton(button)">{{button.value}}</button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.selectButton = function(button) {
    $scope.selectedButton = button.value;
};
```

Comment: i also have an "All" button, on click of which all the videos should be deisplayed. Currently on the click of all button, i am reloading the route.Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You can try setting `selectedButton` to `undefined` or `null`.

If those do not work, then in your view: use `filter:filters` instead of `filter :{type: selectedButton}`. Now you should have a `$scope.filters` object in your controller. You can either set the `type` property or delete it if you want to show all.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit and made a  fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5769/

HTML

```
ng-click="selectButton(button)"
```

Controller:

```
$scope.selectButton = function(btn) {
    $scope.selectedButton = btn.value;
}
```